# Slack - copy name of channel

Tags: slack

I can't seem to copy the name of a channel in Slack!

I've tried:

- double-clicking
- dragging my mouse
- opening the information panel and repeating there
- right clicking it (which only selects the word under the cursor - i.e. not the entire channel name)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Revised answer

*This question will probably no longer be asked, because an intuitive way to copy channel name has been added by Slack since my original answer. For completeness, listing it here.*

Simply right click the channel name and select *Copy name*. This works pretty in every place: sidebar, top bar (under search), channel reference in a message. Another option is using *More* -> *Copy channel name*  in channel details panel on the right.

[image: places where name can be copied from]

---

### Original answer

Open the channel whose name you want to copy and hover over the name. When the cursor changes from arrow to hand, you will be able to select the name of the channel and copy it as usual (Ctrl/Cmd+C or select Copy from context menu).

[image: channel name selected, with context menu open, presenting the standard "Copy" item]

The screenshot is from the desktop app, but this works in a browser as well.

Comment: OK, so this is just a UX issue. The cursor changes to a hand (which implies it's a link and that an action is going to happen if you click on it. However, if you double click on the "link" you can select it. And then right click and Copy).

Answer (score 3):

Just hit Ctrl+F or ⌘+F in channel and you can copy the channel name from opened dialog.
[Opened Search current channel or conversation dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRj27.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try expanding the Highlights section in the side panel - this lets you select the channel name easily:

[image]

Update from @Antenka's comment: the Pinned Items section should also work.

Comment: I haven't had anything under "Highlitght", but I was able to copy from "Pinned items" :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems so trivial, but can't copy it neither :D This workaround works:

- open Slack channel in *Firefox/Chrome*
- right click channel name and choose *Inspect element / Inspect*
- console opens and one line is
  highlighted, looks like *[button id="channel_title"....]*
- double click the line so it expands - name of channel is now visible, *double
  click it / select and copy*